# WPF Application - can't display data from a list in a datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, datagrid

I'm a newbie with WPF and c# and have a (probably very simple) problem.

I'm coding a small application, and i'm trying to read data from a database, format it into a list, and display in a datagrid. Ive debugged it, and it I've successfully read the database, and all the data is in the list (`cd_list`), but it's not passing the data to the datagrid.

Below is my **XAML**:

```
<DataGrid Name="DataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="false" RowHeaderWidth="0" Width="240" >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" ></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Details"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Employee"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Date"></DataGridTextColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

My code behind file does `InitializeComponent`, then does some work to get the data from a DB, and put it in a list of `call_detail` objects:

```
public class call_details
{
    public string name;
    public string details;
    public string employee;
    public string date;

    public call_details()
    {
    }
}
```

Declare list & call detail objects

```
   public call_details cd_rec = new call_details();
   public List<call_details> cd_list = new List<call_details>();
```

Add records to the list

```
   cd_list.Add(cd_rec);
```

After this is done, I am trying to give the ItemsSource so that the data will show in the Datagrid, and have the following:

```
DataGrid.ItemsSource = cd_list;
```

but its not working. In the GUI, the Datagrid shows a grid, with the correct number of records that I expect, but they are all blank.So I guess that it is passing some info, just not the actual data.
It's probably a silly mistake which I have made due to being a novice, but I can't find anything else out there to help me.

Anyone?

Comment: Please do not make repeated changes to questions which put answers out of context. You could make annotations as to what is wrong with the code but among other things that noramlly is the job of the answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All those fields need to be exposed as public properties with at least a getter (this is a requirement of the binding-system). Then you need to bind to the properties or just use the auto-generated columns.

```
public string Name { get; private set; }
```

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" />
```

If you are new to WPF i highly recommend reading some of the [articles on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754130.aspx). e.g. the [Data Binding Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx).

Comment: Made the changes, and am getting data through, but its the last record repeated throughout the datagrid. Need to try and sort this out now...
And MSDN, I've been going around  in cirles on their website for a while...great at explaining the concepts, but not great and giving examples

Comment: If you get the same data multiple times you probably actually added the same object or an identical one to the list multiple times, i have never encountered a case where the DataGrid would produce duplicates on its own.

Comment: Yeah, I had a problem with overwriting all records through the list, got it sorted now. Thank You!